# docker generate node program image when i run docker image this error executed

Tags: node.js, docker

- my Docker File following here
  FROM node:10-alpine

RUN mkdir -p /home/node/app/node_modules && chown -R node:node /home/node/app

WORKDIR /home/node/app

COPY package*.json ./

USER node

RUN npm install

COPY --chown=node:node . .

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["node" "server.js"]

- docker build -t dockerhub_username/nodejs-demo .
- docker images
- docker run --name nodejs-demo -p 80:3000 -d
  dockerhub_username/nodejs-demo

when I execute the following command, occurs some error

docker run 8e5b92236092

- /bin/sh: [node: not found

Comment: seems like a invalid host name, can you post your `Dockerfile`

Comment: Welcome to SO. I advise you read the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) article as it provides very useful information for newcomers on how to write questions. Quality questions help us provide you quality answers - Please edit your question and add `Dockerfile`, `docker run` commands you're using and a brief explanation of the issue.